# Website will not load for certain ISPs

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, isp

My website will not load correctly for certain ISPs. I have verified with both the DNS provider and the website host that all information is 100% correct. However, certain internet providers yield this error message "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN". If I change my local computer's DNS settings to a public one (say cloudfare) the website will load. This issue is not just contained to my computer, as several other people on different computers with a different ISP are also getting the same error. But some reason, others are able to view the website without issue.

Has anyone experienced anything like this before? And were you able to resolve it? I am going in circles talking with the DNS provider and the website host, who both keep telling me everything is correct and to check with the other guy.

Downforeveryoneorjustme.com is saying that is just me and that the website is up. However this has been going on for several weeks now, and the same people cannot load the website. I assume this is a DNS issue with the ISP, but I have no idea how to resolve this.

Comment: **Has anyone experienced anything like this before?** - Probably. **And were you able to resolve it?** - Probably. Why don't you give us the domain name and the FQDN of the website so that we can actually look at it?

Comment: clevelanddesign.com is the domain name. How do I locate the FQDN?

Comment: dnschecker shows no errors for A (v4) and [one error in Singapore for AAAA (v6)](https://dnschecker.org/#AAAA/clevelanddesign.com) -- is it possible the affected users are in or near Singapore and have v6-only connection?

Comment: Thanks for checking. The people who are affected are me in Utah, a coworker in Connecticut and a client in Massachusetts - so all located in the US.

Comment: Looks good to me as well. Next question for troubleshooting would be : What is the IP of the ISP's public DNS resolver?

Your users having issues may also have a local internal domain with the same name, preventing their queries from going out to the internet.

There's many other scenarios, it requires more data to troubleshoot.